# Migration from php 5.3 to php 5.6 and resulting image in src attribute is no longer displayed

Tags: php, image-processing

I have this tag requesting an image blob from a php script ﻿

```
<img src="https://example.org/show_image.php?id=41" width="200" height="142">
```

The php script is

```
$connection = @mysqli_connect($nome_host, $nome_user, $password) or die();  
$in_id = (int) $_GET['id'];  
$res_image=mysqli_query($connection,'SELECT content FROM image WHERE id_image='.$in_id) or die();  
$image = mysqli_fetch_array($res_image);  
header("Content-Type: image/pjpeg");  
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=image.jpg");  
echo $image['content'];
```

Before migrating to php 5.6 it worked, after that the image is not shown and the browser notice "Impossibile caricare l’immagine"
When I debug the script with

```
wget "http://example.org/show_image.php?id=41"
```

the image is downloaded correctly.

Can anyone suggest me what the problem can be? thanks in advance!

Comment: I only see a possible error in line 5: The `Content-Type: image/pjpeg` seems like it should be `Content-Type: image/jpeg` (one p) less.

Comment: @kronn for me too and I tried this but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
The problem is a character (invisible to my IDE) placed before `<?php` within the script, that dirty the header